# Rapidminer group and frequency count

Tags: rapidminer

I have a dataset and want go group same ID's and count the frequency. The aggregation operator offers quite a lot of options, but not this one. Which operator can you suggest?

The event_table lists user_id's, creationdates. Now I want to count home many of the same user_id's are in the list, so to say building groups, counting the frequency - let's say userid 223 -> 21

[image]

I got it by using the Aggregate operator with the group_by attributes and the count aggregation attributes –

[image]

best

M

Comment: Could you give more detail ideally a toy example showing a before and after of your data?

Comment: I got it by using the Aggregate operator with the group_by attributes and the count aggregation attributes